# AngularJS combining the use of two custom directives with shared scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two different custom directives, both having an isolated scope. Is there a way to use both directives on the same element without getting:

Error: Multiple directives [...] asking for isolated scope on ...

I thought that they would share a common scope by doing so but it appears it won't (as I get this error)...

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've workarounded that issue by using the same controller for my both directives, allowing them to share the scope different from the parent scope...

I'm still interested in any suggestion on that subject.

Answer (score 1):

There's a summary of how directive scopes can be combined in the reference to the [$compile method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).

The main points are that isolate scopes are never shared, and that an element can have at most one scope attached to it. If your directives use a child scope instead, then it will be shared between both directives.

> - **no scope + no scope** => Two directives which don't require their own scope will use their parent's scope
> - **child scope + no scope** => Both directives will share one single child scope
> - **child scope + child scope** => Both directives will share one single child scope
> - **isolated scope + no scope** => The isolated directive will use it's own created isolated scope. The other directive will use its parent's
>     scope
> - **isolated scope + child scope** => Won't work! Only one scope can be related to one element. Therefore these directives cannot be applied
>     to the same element.
> - **isolated scope + isolated scope** => Won't work! Only one scope can be related to one element. Therefore these directives cannot be applied
>     to the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think Angular gives you the choice between working with a parent scope and communicating between directives.

You can achieve the latter one by adding an interface in the "master" directive by adding a controller function which the "slave" directive consumes. The slave explicates the dependency via `require: '^masterDirective'` and can use its interface in the `link` function.

See the official explanation with a nice example: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate